# How to query 3 tables in Grails Gorm

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, criteria, projection

I am new to grails framework how to query 3 tables having association between them

```
    Class A{
    static hasMany = [b:B]
    }

    enter code here

    class B{
    long aId // Id of table A 
    }

    class c{
    B b //B reference
    }
```

SQL query: select * from C where b_id in (select id from B where a_id='10'_)

```
Any help will be appreciated.
```

Comment: Use http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight-forward

```
def list = C.withCriteria{
  b{
    eq 'aId', '10'
  }
}
```